# Saving rfc5544 structure to file

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, rfc, rfc3161

I successfully obtained a Timestamp from a tsa server (RFC 3161) and i've created the following Object using bouncyCastle:

```
TimeStampedData timeStampedData = new TimeStampedData(uri, null, asn1OctetString, evid);
```

How can i save this structure to a file (.tsr or .tsd) with RFC 5544 specifications?

I've looked for this all over the bouncycaste wiki and also asked in their forum but i received no answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the RFC 5544 is based on CMS objects you need to wrap the `TimeStampedData` object into a `ContentInfo` with the timestamped-data object identifier as defined in the RFC.

You should call:

```
TimeStampedData timeStampedData = new TimeStampedData(uri, null, asn1OctetString, evid);
ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(CmsObjectIdentifiers.timestampedData, timeStampedData);
Byte[] fileData = contentInfo.GetEncoded();
```

And then store this byte array into a file.

Comment: which extension should i use saving the file with this method? .tsr or .tsd? Thanks

Comment: According to RFC 5955 http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5955.txt the extension should be .tsd. Actually I did not find much information about .tsr extension; only the fact that it should be used to store time-stamp responses as defined in RFC 3161 (i.e the response status along wity the time-stamp token in case of response success)